# Twitter login email

Tags: php, twitter

I am creating application where users can login with Twitter, actually they are registering with Twitter.

My problem is:

If someone tries to login with Twitter I want to check if that user is already registered on my app or not.

How to do that?

With Facebook that is not problem since Facebook returns user_email and I can simply check if that mail is in DB or not, but how to do that with Twitter because Twitter doesn't return email on login?

Comment: Twitter doesn't provide a user's email address.  Why can't you just use buttons which say "Login With Twitter" and "Sign Up For Twitter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution follow this simple 1-5 tutorial on Sign In With Twitter: Introduction (1/5)  [Link Here](http://tubentertain.com/tech-tv/?c=4&xfp=Jp-Yb-lwYkY)